# Make a distinct dataframe based on a column with prioritization condition

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to make a distinct dataframe that if they have the same `product_number`, there is a prioritization about the `product_name`.

Here is the prioritization: **Product A > B > C**

In this table, you can see that there are same `product_number` with different `product_name`.

[image]

How can I make it distinct to something like this?

[image]

For `product_number` 1000003, A has been prioritized.

For `product_number` 1000005, A has been prioritized.

For `product_number` 1000006, B has been prioritized.

*Note: Name of the product is not actually A, B, C nor only 3*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below one -

Example -

1. Dataframe creation with sample data -

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df_pn = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(product_number="1000001", product_name="coil"),
    Row(product_number="1000002", product_name="mouse"),
    Row(product_number="1000003", product_name="coil"),
    Row(product_number="1000003", product_name="laptop"),
    Row(product_number="1000004", product_name="coil"),
    Row(product_number="1000005", product_name="mouse"),
    Row(product_number="1000005", product_name="coil"),
    Row(product_number="1000005", product_name="laptop"),
    Row(product_number="1000006", product_name="mouse"),
    Row(product_number="1000006", product_name="laptop"),
    Row(product_number="1000007", product_name="laptop")
])
```

2. Create a dict to map the priority for each product -

```
product_map = { "coil" : "1", "mouse" : "3", "laptop" : "2" }
```

3. Now map the product name from df in dict -

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, lit, when


mapping_exprsn = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*product_map.items())])

df1 = df_pn.filter(df_pn['product_name'].isNull()).withColumn('product_priority', lit(None))

df2 = df_pn.filter(df_pn['product_name'].isNotNull()).withColumn(
    'product_priority', 
    when(
        df_pn['product_name'].isNotNull(), 
        mapping_exprsn[df_pn['product_name']]
    )
)

result = df1.unionAll(df2)
display(result)
```

4. Create a view -

```
result.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
```

5. Use below query to get final result -

```
select test.product_number, test.product_name from test
join (select min(product_priority) product_priority, first(product_name) as product_name, product_number from test group by product_number) test_agg
on test.product_number=test_agg.product_number
where test.product_priority=test_agg.product_priority
```

Comment: thanks! But the name of the product is not actually A/B/C, so we cannot use min. Sorry I forgot to make it clear in the description. Already added.

Comment: You can have a dict to declare the priority for each products and then map it to get the prioritized product_name for each product_number. Updated the code. Please check whether it works for you.

Comment: Added a query to get the result by creating a temp view.

Comment: What about simply adding a column for the priorities and then using [min_by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.min_by.html) as aggregation function?

Comment: It will be better to maintain the priorities for each product in separate table. So whenever a new product comes, we can update that table and run the code to get the result